# Google Chrome Search Language

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I force my browser to search Google in English?](https://superuser.com/questions/398790/how-can-i-force-my-browser-to-search-google-in-english)

How do I change Chrome's language for omnibox searches? If I just add another search engine for the local version of Google (`http://www.google.com/search?q=%s`) it works, but it does not show suggestions in the drop-down menu any more.

Comment: In Chrome's Search Engine settings it is currently set to `{google:baseURL}search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q=%s` because I clicked OK to getting Google results in Romanian when I arrived in Romania. Was fun for a while but how do I put it back to English with all these secret codes?

Comment: Same here - my Chrome uses google.dk and there is no way to change it... I can put random text instead of default google.com in settings and it still search in dk...

Comment: (cc @hippietrail)

Comment: (cc @WojciechBednarski)

Comment: It does like that is the answer: http://superuser.com/questions/398790/how-can-i-force-my-browser-to-search-google-in-english