# How can I force my browser to search Google in English?

Tags: google-chrome, language

I'm too bored of seeing sites like Google and such show up in my native language, I would rather like them to be in English. Yet, I have to explicitly change the URL to `.com` and `en` and that kind of parameters in order for them to show up in English. Can I somehow force this?

### So, how is Google configured?

However, it is set to English on the site itself **so it has to be my browser**:

[image]

### Then, how does my browser land up on non-english pages, like Google?

It usually shows up in non-English when I'm performing a search, which uses:

```
{google:baseURL}search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:instantFieldTrialGroupParameter}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q=%s
```

When performing a search, it fills these variables in with non-english values.

How can I tell my browser to fill these in with the English values?

My Google Chrome options give preference to English:

[image]

Comment: I'm sure that this has been asked before, but I can't find the duplicate right now.

Comment: When you go to google.com, does it redirect you? What happens if you click the "Use google.com in English" link (or similar) at the bottom?

Comment: @slhck: It doesn't redirect me if I do that, in that case it is in English. If I click the link it doesn't remember that for the next time. It is really Google Chrome that literally fills in `{google:baseURL}` with `https://www.google.be/`...

Comment: [How do I revert Chrome's Google search to English after experimenting with the new Chrome feature that detects when I change country?](http://superuser.com/q/306171)

Comment: It doesn't save for me

Comment: https://www.google.com/?hl=en using the [hl](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=en#hlsp) parameter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data` there is a file `Local State` which contains the `{google:baseURL}` information. While temporarily closing Google Chrome, I simply filled in the URL `https://www.google.com` instead which resolved my problem:

```
{
   "browser": {
      "enabled_labs_experiments": [ "conflicting-modules-check",
                                    "extension-apis", "preload-instant-search",
                                    "print-preview" ],
      "hung_plugin_detect_freq": 2000,
      "last_known_google_url": "https://www.google.com/",
      "last_prompted_google_url": "https://www.google.com/",
      "last_redirect_origin": "",
      "plugin_message_response_timeout": 30000
   },
```

Comment: What name it is in Lion? I can't see `Local State` file in `Application Support`. Thanks.

Comment: @WojciechBednarski: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` else I don't know...

Comment: This is only for Chrome; the [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/398790/how-can-i-force-my-browser-to-search-google-in-english/560528#560528) by [Volodymyr](http://superuser.com/users/167571/volodymyr) works for all browser.

Answer (score 16):

There are two options available for configuration:

**which language should Google products use**

**which language(s) should be used for search results**

Open Google Chrome, in address bar type in: `http://www.google.com/preferences#languages`

You can configure more than 1 language for search results, while only 1 can be set for Google products.

Configure appropriate settings and Save them.

[image]

Comment: Does this work? I set only English to both fields but still got the results in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome, you can force all Google services to use English with this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/english-please/lkhoknaphajfjdcpnllakeglfpbbimhp

**Update 2023:**
The extension is offline, but the repo is still there at
https://github.com/spajus/english-please
with the logic in [background.js](https://github.com/spajus/english-please/blob/master/background.js):

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function (details) {
    var url = new Url(details.url);
    if (details.type == 'main_frame' && url.query.hl != 'en') {
      url.query.hl = 'en';
      return { redirectUrl: url.toString() };
    }
  },
  { urls: ["*://*.google.com/*"] },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

It inserts the [hl param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271747/what-does-hl-stand-for) into URLs containing google.com.