# Google Chrome is in Danish

Tags: google-chrome

I'm not sure what i have done, but by default, Chrome comes up in Danish.  I can ignore this most of the time but its v annoying and i cant seem to change it.  For example google directions come up in Danish too and have to be translated back to English!

I have tried the spanner icon, and i've confirmed the only two languages specified are En and US English.

Does anyone have any ideas how i can default it back to English all the time.

[image]

In-lined the original screenshot from www.cow-shed.co.uk

Thanks

Comment: Your screenshot shows the Google web site in Danish, not Google Chrome.

Comment: It also shows you logged in to the Google website.

Comment: Personally I'd consider that to be a feature rather than a bug :)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Det er sgu ingen feature, nej.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the comments of your post, I think you need to just set your home page to www.google.com.

You may also want to try to set your language here http://www.google.co.uk/preferences?hl=en#languages

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make Chrome stop using localized Google search, see the following threads:

- [Why does Google Chrome ignore "last_known_google_url" property in "Local State" file?](https://superuser.com/questions/468794/why-does-google-chrome-ignore-last-known-google-url-property-in-local-state)
- [Set preferred language in Chrome and other Google services](https://superuser.com/questions/408446/set-preferred-language-in-chrome-and-other-google-services)
- [How can I force my browser to search Google in English?](https://superuser.com/questions/398790/how-can-i-force-my-browser-to-search-google-in-english)